# undefined method `get_best_compatible' for nil:Class appearing randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Few days ago we started facing issue when sending emails from our Rails application.
Here is a backtrace of the error :

```
mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/body.rb:143→ get_best_encoding
mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/body.rb:156→ encoded
mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:1710→ encoded
actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:434→ set_payload_for_mail
actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:414→ block in deliver_mail
activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123→ block in instrument
activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20→ instrument
activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123→ instrument
actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:413→ deliver_mail
mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:229→ deliver
!===> app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:16→ create <===!
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4→ send_action
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167→ process_action
```

I have highlighted the line that points to our code. The rest is gem / rails code.
It may be important to note that in this environment we are sending some of our email via delayed_job and some others without it. This stack trace above refers to an email sent without delayed_job.

We have been able to reproduce the problem in a dev environment where we have applied the following changes :

- Rails has been bumped to 3.2.9 instead of 3.2.8
- Ruby has been bumped to 1.9.3-p327 instead of 1.9.3-p194
- Delayed_job now sends *all* emails. And has been bumped to 3.0.4 instead of 3.0.3

Here is a backtrace of the error in the dev environment :

```
mail (2.4.4) lib/mail/body.rb:143:in `get_best_encoding'
mail (2.4.4) lib/mail/body.rb:156:in `encoded'
mail (2.4.4) lib/mail/message.rb:1710:in `encoded'
actionmailer (3.2.9) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:434:in `set_payload_for_mail'
actionmailer (3.2.9) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:414:in `block in deliver_mail'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionmailer (3.2.9) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:413:in `deliver_mail'
mail (2.4.4) lib/mail/message.rb:229:in `deliver'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb:6:in `perform'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:95:in `block in invoke_job'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:92:in `invoke_job'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:37:in `block in enqueue'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:36:in `tap'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:36:in `enqueue'
delayed_job (3.0.4) lib/delayed/message_sending.rb:13:in `method_missing'
!===> app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:16:in `create' <===!
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
```

As far as we can see, it seems to be exactly the same stack trace, apart from the delayed_job part and from the gem version.

The line 16 of our application controller looks like this in our dev environment :

```
UserMailer.delay(:queue => "mail").password_reset_instructions(@user)
```

in prod it is :

```
UserMailer.password_reset_instructions(@user).deliver
```

The tricky part is that this bug is "random". It does not occur every single time, and when it does not occur, mails are sent successfully.

Here are two observation :

- When the bug occur once for an email, it will occur every time, for the same email. By "same email", I mean same action in the same controller, regardless of the parameters.
- Thus, one email can be bugged, while the others are OK.
- Restarting the server always fixes the problem, for all emails. But only for a while.
- We have yet to find a sequence of operation that would trigger the error with a 100% confidence.

We have been investigating that bug for a few days, but we really are hitting a wall here. DO you have any idea of what we might be doing wrong ?